# Minecraft glitching out on PC

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I'm playing Minecraft right and than I relog because I'm logged in and my screen looks like this [image: What I'm seeing]

I'm so lost can anyone help me please my render distance is on 2 and I put my graphics fancy fast all that, does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: Tried updating your graphics card drivers?

Comment: Are you stuck?  This looks like you are inside blocks.  I do also recommend trying @Jason_'s awnser

Comment: That is what it looks like when you spawn inside of blocks like @Jcraft153 said. Try digging out or if you have to do /kill to go to your spawnpoint.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Vertex Buffer Objects(VBOs) problem, it should increase your FPS by 5% to 10% on average.  Check under your video settings and look for VBOs.  Turn them on if they are off.

If this doesn't fix your problem try allowing Minecraft more access to your computers memory.  Here is a step by step tutorial: http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/unmodified-minecraft-client/tutorials-and-faqs/1871637-tutorial-allocate-more-memory-for-minecraft

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvTwVC-i7Ew) on how to do it.

**Note** There is a different way to do it for 1.9